# Opening session in PuTTY from WinSCP stops at "Login as" prompt instead of using credentials from WinSCP

Tags: putty, winscp

I'm facing strange issue with WinSCP: It works well and I'm able to connect to remote hosts. But when I try to use the *"Open session in PuTTY"*, instead of logging me directly with same credentials, PuTTY gets "stuck", prompting me to *"login as"*.

I've checked the config in WinSCP and it looks fine: *"Remember session password and pass it to PuTTY"* is ticked.

What else should I check?

I'm using WinSCP 4.2.7 and PuTTY 0.60.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#session_configuration):

> By default, WinSCP creates temporary site settings for PuTTY (under the name *"WinSCP temporary session"*). The site settings will contain only the options known by WinSCP, mostly connection options. It will particularly lack any terminal options, so the defaults (*Default Settings* profile) will apply.
>
> **If you want to configure your own options, you can save PuTTY site settings with the same name as a WinSCP site. WinSCP will then instruct PuTTY to open that session (It will not export any settings, nor a connection options).**

So if you have an invalid stored session in PuTTY with the same name as your WinSCP stored site, the *"Open in PuTTY"* function won't work, as it tries to open that invalid site.

---

Side note: You are using an obsolete and insecure versions of WinSCP and PuTTY. You urgently need to upgrade!

Comment: Thanks, I had missed this! And yes, you're correct, the phrasing of the question could be better : I updated it

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP is somehow looking into PuTTY saved sessions that are configured. I had a saved session in PuTTY with same name as in WinSCP (*"myApplication - integration"*). Somehow, when the session already exist in PuTTY, WinSCP is not able to log me in directly to PuTTY.

I deleted the saved session from PuTTY, and it worked: now WinSCP logs me in directly in PuTTY. And now I see a *"WinSCP temporary session"* in the list of saved session in PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

We need provide putty path
Right click the putty icon in WinSCP then go to Queue -> Customize -> Application
then provide your putty.exe path using browse button
then click ok

Now click the putty icon button from WinSCP, Putty will open automatically :)

[image]

Comment: Well, that's not an answer to the question. The question says *"instead of logging me directly with same credentials, Putty gets "stuck", prompting me to "login as"."* – With a wrong path, the PuTTY won't even start.

Answer (score -1):

1. In WinSCP Go to  :

   preferencce - > integration -> application
2. under "putty/terminal client path" add this line :

   %ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\putty.exe -t -m "%TEMP%\putty.txt" !`cmd.exe /c echo  cd '!/' ; /bin/bash -login > "%TEMP%\putty.txt"`

Comment: Can you explain how exactly does this solve the specific problem OP was having?